# Long division of polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I am reading a math history book which says:

> "Gregory could have learned in Italy that the area under the curve $y=1 / (1+x^2)$, from
>   $x=0$ to $x=x$, is arctan x, and a simple long division converts $
> 1 / (1+x^2)$ to  $1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6+...$"

Can someone please explain how is

$1/(1+x^2)  = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6+...$

And

How do you perform long divison of this kind?

Thanks.

Comment: I won't comment on the long division, but notice the geometric sum
$$
\frac{1}{1-t} = 1+t+t^2 +t^3 + \ldots
$$
There's an easy way to obtain your result from this ...

Comment: Write the numerator as $1+x^2-x^2+x^4-x^4+x^6-x^6+x^8-x^8....etc$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knowledge of geometric series tells me that

$$\frac1{1-z}=\sum_{n\ge 0}z^n=1+z+z^2+z^3+\ldots\;;$$

if I now set $z=-x^2$, I find that

$$\frac1{1+x^2}=\sum_{n\ge 0}(-x^2)^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^nx^{2n}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+-\ldots\;.$$

That said, it *is* possible to do the long division, with a little ingenuity:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac1{1+x^2}&=\frac{(1+x^2)-x^2}{1+x^2}\\
&=1-\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\\
&=1-\frac{(x^2+x^4)-x^4}{1+x^2}\\
&=1-\frac{x^2(1+x^2)-x^4}{1+x^2}\\
&=1-x^2+\frac{x^4}{1+x^2}\\
&=1-x^2+\frac{(x^4+x^6)-x^6}{1+x^2}\\
&=1-x^2+\frac{x^4(1+x^2)-x^6}{1+x^2}\\
&=1-x^2+x^4-\frac{x^6}{1+x^2}\\
&\;\;\vdots
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Brian: Hope you don't mind I leave a non-mathematical question here. The closing/deleting clique has been vandalizing the site all the time with the gun of context nonsense. How do you make a peace with that and continue useful interactions?

Comment: @user987907: I am simply responding to questions about old answers of mine and correcting any typos or other errors that I or others find in them; I am no longer even looking at new questions.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+x^2)(1-x^2+x^4+\dots)$$

$$=(1-x^2+x^4+\dots)$$

$$+x^2(1-x^2+x^4+\dots)$$

$$=(1-x^2+x^4+\dots)$$

$$+(x^2-x^4+x^6+\dots)$$

$$=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Use binomial theorem 
$$(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)x^2}{2!}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)x^3}{3!}+...$$
Replace x by $x^2 $ and n=-1

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an instance of long division being used. Rather, we know that for every $|r| <1$, the geometric series

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} r^n = \frac{1}{1-r}$$

Replacing $r = -x^2$ in the expression above yields the desired result (being careful to note that $|x| < 1$ must be true for the equality to hold).